# How to create a dex with D8.bat

Tags: android, android-studio, dex, dx, android-d8

I used to create dex file with dx.bat like this :

> "c:\SDKs\android\build-tools\32.0.0\dx.bat" --dex
> --output=C:\Dev\MagicFoundation\Alcinoe\Tools\AddRJavaToClassesDex\tmp\classes.dex
> C:\Dev\MagicFoundation\Alcinoe\Tools\AddRJavaToClassesDex\tmp\obj.zip

How to do the same with d8.bat?

Answer (score 2):

Creating DEX file using d8 can be achieved using:

```
d8 --output <output-folder> <input-files>
```

In your case, the following is an equivalent:

```
c:\SDKs\android\build-tools\32.0.0\d8.bat --output C:\Dev\MagicFoundation\Alcinoe\Tools\AddRJavaToClassesDex\tmp C:\Dev\MagicFoundation\Alcinoe\Tools\AddRJavaToClassesDex\tmp\obj.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

To anyone who is using `d8.bat` with OpenJDK-11, if you encounter the error when running `d8.bat`:

> -Djava.ext.dirs=${PathToAndroidSDK}\build-tools${BuildToolVersion}\lib is not supported.  Use -classpath instead.
>
> Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
>
> Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

You can edit `d8.bat` with a text editor, replacing the code `-Djava.ext.dirs="%frameworkdir%"` in last line to `-classpath "%frameworkdir%"` to fix the error.